# Can my friend sell an 'Eiffel Tower' with NFT

Tags: nft

Suppose I know someone who has ownership over a landmark. Not quite the Eiffel Tower, but to ensure he remains anonymous we could say it is a similar asset. Perhaps simpler because it just sits there without people going inside.

Can he now sell an NFT for this? Does he have to provide proof to someone that he has the rightful ownership of the landmark before creating the NFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically anyone can create an NFT and sell it.  In your example, it is like taking a picture, putting it on a website, and having a payment method.

Because anybody (with the technical skills or help) can do it, the provenance of the NFT is one of the important parts.  An NFT created by the official website or owner, will typically be more valuable than an NFT created by an unknown person.

Comment: Does that mean there can be more than 1 NFT for said 'eiffel tower' at the same time?

Comment: Multiple NFTs can point to the identical picture.  But each NFT is like a number on the blockchain, and is unique.